# Java programming do loops and libraries

Tags: java

Here goes. I am having trouble with an assignment in Java.  We are asked to create a program where the user needs to guess letters from a missing phrase.  I created the phrase and replaced each character with a ?, but now the user needs to guess. How do I construct the for loop to reveal each character if the user is correct.  This is what I have so far on eclipse.

```
    public static void main(String[]args)
 {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    String cPhrase = "be understaning";
    char g;
    boolean found;
    String guessed;

    System.out.println("\tCommon Phrase");
    System.out.println("_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _");
    System.out.println(cPhrase.replaceAll("[a-z]", "?"));
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print(" Enter a lowercase letter guess: ");

    g = stdIn.nextLine();  // I am trumped right  here not sure what to do?
                                      // Can't convert char to str
    for (int i = 0; i < cPhrase.length(); ++i)
    {
        if( cPhrase.charAt(i) == g)
            {
            found = true;
            }
        if (found)
        {
            guessed += g;
```

Comment: This is not an [tag:eclipse] question.

Comment: Your code example is incomplete - braces have been left unclosed. Presumably you have something that at least compiles?

Comment: Please post a full [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (which is just the complete, runnable code). And also format the code before posting it here (in Eclipse, just press Ctrl+Shift+F with everything selected). Nicely stated question otherwise. +1 (coming as soon as I get votes again :D)

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/557282/java/java/Phrase-Guessing-Game-Help Here is an example refer it.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

Use a while instead of a for loop tied to a boolean condition. The boolean would be set to false if and only if all characters in word guessed.

Comment: The for-loop is to check if the char is contained in the phrase, not to loop the guessing.

Comment: @Rouby Good catch! Yes. A while might wrap the existing impl.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply get the first char of the input-line (assuming one should just guess one char at a time)

```
g = stdIn.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

To loop until the user has guessed the whole phrase you need to surround the code with a `while`.

```
while(not complete)
{
  get input
  process input
  show progress
}
```

Comment: and don't forget to initialize the Variables `boolean found` and `String guessed`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick soluition. But please dont just copy-paste, you still need to understand it (therefor i put inline-comments in).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    String phrase = "be understanding";
    boolean[] guessed = new boolean[phrase.length()];
    // walk thru the phrase and set all non-chars to be guessed
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
        if (!phrase.substring(i, i + 1).matches("[a-z]"))
            guessed[i] = true;

    // loop until we break out
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Please guess a char: ");
        char in = stdIn.nextLine().charAt(0);

        boolean allGuessed = true;
        System.out.print("Phrase: ");
        // walk over each char in the phrase
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = phrase.charAt(i);
            // and check if he matches the input
            if (in == c)
                guessed[i] = true;
            // if we have an not already guessed char, dont end it
            if (!guessed[i])
                allGuessed = false;
            // print out the char if it is guessed (note the ternary if operator)
            System.out.print(guessed[i] ? c : "?");
        }
        System.out.println("\n------------------");
        // if all chars are guessed break out of the loop
        if (allGuessed)
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("Congrats, you solved the puzzle!");

    stdIn.close();
}
```